# How to make one keystroke emit three Unicode characters in a custom keyboard layout in Linux Mint?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have created a custom keyboard layout for my regional language
by editing different files.  It works fine except for one problem. 
One of the characters needs three Unicode characters in combination,
i.e., I want all three characters to be emitted
from a single keystroke. 
Please help me to do so.

The characters are as follows

`ক + ্ + ষ --> ক্ষ`

`U0995 + U09CD + U09B7 --> ক্ষ`

This combination must be emitted from the third character of the key `key <AB04>`, shown below.

I added a language file to the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` and an entry to the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` file.

Extract from the file I added:

```
// shift, z to /
      // key <LFSH> { [ Shift_L ] };
               key <AB01> { [ U09A2,    U09A7,  U09B7,  voidsymbol ] };
               key <AB02> { [ U09A3,    U09A8,  U09B8,  voidsymbol  ] };
               key <AB03> { [ U09AA,    U09AF,  U09B9,  voidsymbol  ] };
               key <AB04> { [ U09AB,    U09F0,  voidsymbol, voidsymbol ] };
               key <AB05> { [ U09AC,    U09B2,  U09DC,  voidsymbol ] };
               key <AB06> { [ U09AD,    U09F1,  U09DD,  voidsymbol ] };
               key <AB07> { [ U09AE,    U09B6,  U09DF,  voidsymbol ] };
```

You need to add the letter ক্ষ to the 3rd position of the 6th key
from the left in the <kbd>Shift</kbd> row.

[image: keyboard layout]

I am using Linux Mint 21.3.

Edit:
What works: All the letters or characters that can be written with one Unicode character can be written with my custom symbols file. The character ক্ষ is a combination of three Unicode characters that can't be written like this.

[image: Assamese alphabet]

See the first letter of the second-to-last line in the alphabet in the image. I can not write it with one key, as `U0995 + U09CD + U09B7` can't be added to the file. This doesn't work.

Wikipedia reference: [Assamese alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assamese_alphabet).

Answer (score 0):

use `XCompose` to define custom compose key sequences.using `XCompose`, you can define custom compose key sequences to emit complex characters or combinations of characters from a single keystroke

```
vi ~/.XCompose
<Multi_key> <k> <c> : "ক্ষ"  # Add your desired key combination here
```

reload the `XCompose` file  by restarting your X session  or by

```
 xim -R
```

Tweak this approach to get desired result i.e. when you press the `compose key` followed by the chosen key combination (e.g., `<Compose> + k + c`), it should emit the `combined character ক্ষ`.

**1 key solution approach**

The above answer was for key combo. If you want to implement this with just 1 key, life will be tougher !
You 'll have to Define a `custom key` in your `keyboard layout configuration` using `custom keymaps and XKB extensions`

- Define a Custom Key: Edit keyboard layout configuration file `(/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/your_layout)` and assign a `keycode` to a custom key.

  ```
   key <AB04> { [ custom_key_symbol ] };
  ```
- Write a `Custom XKB Extension`:

It should listen for the `key press event` of the custom key and emit the sequence of `Unicode characters corresponding to ক্ষ (U+0995 + U+09CD + U+09B7` in C or other compatible language

- Install and Load the Extension: Compile the `custom XKB extension` & install. Then, configure  `XKB environment` to load the `extension` along with your `keyboard layout.`

*Comment : Could you please provide little guidance about how to implement for "Define a custom key in your keyboard layout configuration using custom keymaps and XKB extensions"? About how to define a custom key.*

Edit keyboard layout file in   `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` ( `mkdir`  in case it isnt there ) directory.

**Identify   Keycode**: Determine   keycode you want to assign to your custom key. Keycodes represent physical keys on your keyboard.

**Choose a Custom Key Symbol**:

**Edit   Keyboard Layout Configuration**:

- Navigate to   directory containing   keyboard layout files, typically located at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`.
- Find   appropriate layout file for your language or layout variant. e.g. US layout,  its `us` file  & edit it using `vi`  ( or equivalent )
- Define your custom key by adding an entry to   layout file. Use   chosen custom key symbol  &  assign it to   desired `keycode`. `showkey` commamd  displays   `keycode` of pressed keys on   console . run it in a terminal  &  press any key to see its keycode.

````
```bash
 key <AB04> { [ custom_key_symbol ] };
 ```

 Replace `<AB04>` with   keycode of   key you want to customize,  &  `custom_key_symbol` with   name of your custom key symbol.
````

Comment: yes but, as far as I understand, OPs want the character *to be emitted from a **single** keystroke*.

Comment: didnt notice that . @Op seriously you want that complex letter come off a single stoke or combo is fine. I will   scratch my hair a bit and revert back

Comment: Could you please provide little guidance about how to implement for "Define a custom key in your keyboard layout configuration using custom keymaps and XKB extensions"? About how to define a custom key.

Comment: @RituLahkar See  Updated answer

Comment: I have edited `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` as I have mentioned in the question. But `key <AB04> { [ U0995 + U09CD + U09B7 ] };` does not work. As we cannot add 3 unicode like this. It works with one unicode.

Comment: Need to  scratch your head behind this. I gave you a head start approach " a Custom XKB Extension:

It should listen for the key press event "